# Why is Window.top inaccessable

Tags: c#

Working my way through a C# Textbook, completely new to the language, and have no idea how to fix this error: I am getting an error that reads: **Window.top is inaccessible due to its protection level**, this only occurred after adding the Button class, and I had no problem with the ListBox class: Below is my code:

```
using System;

public class Window {
    private int top;
    private int left;

    public Window(int top, int left) {
        this.top = top;
        this.left = left;
    }
    public virtual void DrawWindow() {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing Window at {0}, {1}", top, left);
    }
}

public class ListBox : Window {
    private string mListBoxContents;
    public ListBox(int top, int left, string theContents): base(top, left) {
        mListBoxContents = theContents;
    }
    public override void DrawWindow() {
        base.DrawWindow();
        Console.WriteLine("Wrting string to the listbox: {0}", mListBoxContents);
    }
}

public class Button : Window {
    public Button(int top, int left): base(top, left) {
    }
        public override void DrawWindow() {
            base.DrawWindow();
            Console.WriteLine("Drawing a button at {0}, {1}", top, left);
        }
    }

public class WindowDriver {
    public static void Main() {

        Window w = new Window(5,10);
        ListBox lb = new ListBox(20,30,"Hello World!");
        Button b = new Button(5,6);

        Window[] winArray = new Window[3];
        winArray[0] = w;
        winArray[1] = lb;
        winArray[2] = b;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            winArray[i].DrawWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The line `Console.WriteLine("Drawing a button at {0}, {1}", top, left);` is trying to access fields or properties named `top` and `left` which are  `private` in the `Window` base class. You need to find/add a more visible equivalent from the base class, or store `top` and `left` from the `Button` constructor locally so you can recall them later.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ isn't storing top and left from the constructor what base(top, left) is supposed to do.

Comment: They are local to the base class then; when the modifier is `private`, only `Window` can access those fields. Change `private int top;` to `protected int top;` in `Window` and then the issue will change to `Window.left is innaccessible...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the lines in the Window class:

```
private int top;
private int left;
```

to:

```
protected int top;
protected int left;
```

Comment: While this is technically correct, it would be helpful to explain *why* making this change is necessary for the application to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You probably tried to access Window.top from the derived class Button. Child classes cannot access private variables of its parent class. If you want to access Window.top from Button, you should change its access specifier to internal or protected.

Comment: or better yet create a getter to return the value(s)

Comment: @Sorceri That's true, I think the other answers covered that possibility too. Regardless, looks like OP answered his own question by changing the fields to protected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Button class is trying to access the private members of Window.

```
public class Window {
    private int top;  //these two members are private which means only the containing class can access them.
    private int left;

    public Window(int top, int left) {
        this.top = top;
        this.left = left;
    }
    public virtual void DrawWindow() {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing Window at {0}, {1}", top, left);
    }
}

public class Button : Window {
    public Button(int top, int left): base(top, left) {
    }

    public override void DrawWindow() {
        base.DrawWindow();
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing a button at {0}, {1}", top, left); // Here you are trying to access the private members of the base class which is not allowed.  This is what is causing your error
    }
}
```

The easiest way to fix the problem is to change the declaration of top and left to protected.  Derived classes have access to protected members, e.g.

```
public class Window {
    protected int top;  //these two members are now protected private which means derived classes can access them.
    protected int left;  

    public Window(int top, int left) {
        this.top = top;
        this.left = left;
    }
    public virtual void DrawWindow() {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing Window at {0}, {1}", top, left);
    }
}
```

If you want to find out more about c# access modifiers check out: [C# Access Modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The line `Console.WriteLine("Drawing a button at {0}, {1}", top, left);` is trying to access the fields `top` and `left` which are  `private` in the `Window` base class. The `private` access modifier is preventing the child class from accessing its parent's fields.

If you only want to be able to set the fields via the base class' constructor, then I would refactor `Window` to replace the two private fields with properties where you can decide the access modifier for both the getter and setter:

```
public class Window 
{
    protected int Top { get; private set; }
    protected int Left { get; private set; }

    public Window (int top, int left) 
    {
        Top = top;
        Left = left;
    }

    public virtual void DrawWindow() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing Window at {0}, {1}", Top, Left);
    }
}
```

Now you'll be able to access the `Top` and `Left` properties in any derived class:

```
public class Button : Window 
{
    public Button(int top, int left)
        : base(top, left) 
    {
    }

    public override void DrawWindow() 
    {
        base.DrawWindow();
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing a button at {0}, {1}", Top, Left);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might want to use a read only property instead of an instance variable:

```
public class Window 
{
    protected int Top { get; }
    protected int Left { get; }

    public Window(int top, int left) 
    {
        Top = top;
        Left = left;
    }

    // Rest of code...
}
```

Then you can access it from any class that inherits `Window`:

```
public class Button : Window
{
    public Button(int top, int left): base(top, left) 
    {
    }

    public override void DrawWindow() 
    {
        base.DrawWindow();
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing a button at {0}, {1}", Top, Left);
    }
}
```

There are different [access modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7(v=vs.100).aspx) in C#.

I used `protected` in my example (meaning only the class, and classes that inherit from it can access the member).  If you need the property to be accessible from any class, change the modifier to `public`.

If you want the ability to change the value of Top/Left after its been initially set, then you want to add a "setter" to your property:

```
protected int Top { get; set; }
```